# How to get hdd transfer mode?

Tags: c#, c++, dma

I need to get hdd transfer mode(dma or pio) and print it, you can find it in device manager(in red circle in the screenshot).[image: AtaScreen]

So I need to get the info in red circle from programm. I've tried to use wmi classes, but Win32_DiskDrive, Win32_IDEController and others dont't provide the information I need. The closest to the property window from device manager was Win32_IDEController, field Win32_IDEController["Name"] returns string `ATA Channel 1`.

Also I've found this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550142(v=vs.85).aspx , but it use `irb.h`, that is part of ddk(wdk) and I've never used it before, so I don't even know how to use this function.

Now I'm learning the WDK) Any solution in any language will good, in project I'm using C#, but if the solution will be in another language I can write "DMA" or "PIO" to a file in this solution, execute it .exe from C# and read from file. OFC solution in C# will be appreciated more.

Comment: Do you have an english version? it's difficult to understand exactly where does reside this information in device manager

Comment: @SimonMourier DeviceManager -> IDE ATA/ATAPI Controllers -> dropdown, right click on the one of channel and choose `properties` -> advanced properties(second tab). Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried AdapterUsesPio from the STORAGE_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTOR structure (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800832.aspx), I have posted an example here: http://pastebin.com/LSHCy08y but I can't test since I don't have IDE drives.

Comment: @SimonMourier Fantastic, I'm really greatfull for the link and the code example. My solution with WMI has been cancelled, so an hour ago I've finally found the DeviceIoControl. At this moment I was working with DeviceIoControl and use it in incorrect way. The WINAPI is really big and sometimes it hard to find out the things I need, maybe you know some books/resources that can help to beginner in hardware to use winapi?

Comment: @SimonMourier Is there is a way to put reward to a comment(or you can post the answer)? Your comment was really helpfull.

Comment: I've posted my answer. I don't know of a good book to help for this kind of answer in general, only MSDN and the SDK's headers. grep on the windows include .h files is in fact quite a good tool for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AdapterUsesPio` member from the [STORAGE_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800832.a%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bspx) structure. Here is a C++ example that demonstrates how to query a disk for it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
    wchar_t path[1024];
    wsprintf(path, L"\\\\?\\C:"); // or L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"

    // note we use 0, not GENERIC_READ to avoid the need for admin rights
    // 0 is ok if you only need to query for characteristics
    HANDLE device = CreateFile(path, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);
    if (device == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;

    STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY query = {};
    query.PropertyId = StorageAdapterProperty;
    query.QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery;

    STORAGE_ADAPTER_DESCRIPTOR descriptor = {};

    DWORD read;
    if (!DeviceIoControl(device, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
        &query,
        sizeof(query),
        &descriptor,
        sizeof(descriptor),
        &read,
        NULL
        ))
    {
        wprintf(L"DeviceIoControl error: %i\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"AdapterUsesPio: %i\n", descriptor.AdapterUsesPio);
    }

    CloseHandle(device);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I've started a new jorney with a lot of google, msdn and questions on forums http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544994/how-to-get-hdd-ata-standards-from-c . Maybe you know something?

Answer (score 3):

You can use autoit (https://www.autoitscript.com) to read it direct from the GUI.

Sample (be carefull with different Windows versions and different languages):

```
    Run ("mmc c:\windows\system32\devmgmt.msc") 
    WinWaitActive ( "Device Manager" ) 
    send("{tab}{down}{down}{down}{down}{down}{down}{down}{NUMPADADD}{down}!{enter}") 
    WinWaitActive ( "Primary IDE Channel Properties" ) 
    send("^{tab}") 
    $drivemode = ControlGetText("Primary IDE Channel Properties", "", "Static4") 
    ControlClick("Primary IDE Channel Properties","Cancel","Button6") 
    WinKill ( "Device Manager" )
```

If you want to use Autoit in C#:

https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/177167-using-autoitx-from-c-net/